# Phpstorm debug JS on project like Magento

Tags: javascript, magento, debugging, phpstorm

I'm trying to debug Js using phpstorm on a Magento project but I cannot figure out how.
I have installed the [JetBrain plug-in for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/related?hl=en) but still I miss something.

According to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48hpCUkB7Zc) looks I have to *run* a precise page on the project so I think this is not a good option for project like Magento that "relay on a single page" ( index.php )

Am I wrong ? any other suitable method beside using the developer tool.

Comment: you don't necessary need to run a precise page - just specify the url you normally use to load your allication in browser as a 'URL:' in JavaScript Debug run configuration